# Unable to Update Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: update-alternatives

Pop up states:

```
Cannot obtain lock E: Could not get lock/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend.
It is held by process 2197 (unattended-upgr) 
W: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system. 
E: Unable to aquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?"
```

What should I do? I do not know if another process is using it!

Comment: You should wait and try again later.

Answer (score 3):

That error is telling you that `unattended-upgrades` is currently working on updates.

You need to wait for it to finish.

When it's done you can continue with your manual updates.

Answer (score 0):

I did wait; then updated every fetched update except the ones' that had the prefix "lib";  then I updated the "lib";  everyone did successfully install.